# Having host filesystem visible to singularity container

Tags: singularity-container

I use singularity images that do not require any binding of the desired host path, i.e.

```
singularity exec image.simg IMAGE_COMMAND -i $PWD/input_file -o ./output_dir
```

simply works like any other command on the "input_file" in my host system, also using relative paths as in "-o".

I'm not comfortable enough with Singularity and its jargon to understand how this is made.

- Is a configuration done in `singularity.conf`?
- How is this feature called? (is it "MOUNT HOSTFS"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, both your home and current directories are mounted/bound into the image for you. You can modify this in `singularity.conf`. [Details on the settings are available in the admin documentation](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/admin-guide/configfiles.html#session-directory-and-system-mounts).

The `MOUNT HOSTFS` in the config is a toggle to automatically mount all host filesystems into the image. `MOUNT HOME` is the corresponding setting for auto-mounting the user's `HOME` directory.

You can see which files/directories are currently being mounted by using the `--verbose` option with your singularity command.

Comment: This document also helped me a lot:
https://nf-co.re/usage/troubleshooting#cannot-find-input-files-when-using-singularity